# How can I call a method and pass arguments when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I this code:

```
        correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(AS.cfs, AS.phrase); 

            correctAns++;
            AS.pointsCount[(int)AS.cfs]++;
            scoreCountLabel.Text = FontAwesome.FAStop.Repeat(correctAns);
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
            {
                switch (AS.cardOrder)
                {
                    case CardOrder.FirstToLast:
                        AS.orderPhraseIndex++;
                        AS.phraseIndexList.Add(AS.orderPhraseIndex);
                        getPhraseFirstToLast();
                        break;
                    case CardOrder.Random:
                        getRandomNumber();
                        getRandomPhrase();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            });
        };
```

I would like to move the code that's run into a method and pass the arguments also.  But how can I call that method when the correctButton is clicked?

Comment: make a method `void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)` and attach it event: `correctButton.Clicked += MyMethod;`

Comment: Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
correctButton.Clicked += correctButtonClicked;

protected void correctButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // code goes here
}
```